# return sorted array in lexicographical order python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, filter

```
a1 = ['arp', 'bull', 'mice']
a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
```

I need it to return:

```
['arp']
```

My code is:

```
def in_array(array1, array2):
    x = array1
    return sorted(x)
```

which works for:

```
a1 = ["live", "arp", "strong"] 
a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
r = ['arp', 'live', 'strong']
```

How do I sort through an array and only match the sorted elements that are substrings of a2?

Comment: Do you want to *sort*? or *filter*?

Comment: I want to sort and filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `filter` and check whether there is `any(..)` element in `a2` that contains such a substring:

```
def in_array(a1,a2):
    return filter(lambda e1: any(e1 in e2 for e2 in a2),a1)
```

In case you want the result to be sorted as well, you can use `sorted(..)`:

```
def in_array(a1,a2):
    return sorted(filter(lambda e1: any(e1 in e2 for e2 in a2),a1))
```

If you want to eliminate duplicates, you can use `set(..)`:

```
def in_array(a1,a2):
    return sorted(set(filter(lambda e1: any(e1 in e2 for e2 in a2),a1)))
```

The algorithm will run in *O(n×m+n×log(n))* with *n* the number of elements in `a1`, and *m* the number of elements in `a2`.

You can boost the algorithm complexity in terms of *O(n)* in case you can do preprocessing on `ar2` (and generate for instance a trie). But this is only beneficial if the number of elements in `a1` is huge compared to the number of elements in `a2`.

Comment: Thank you for this! It passed all but 1 test now. I need it to not return duplicates (return only 1 copy). I am unfamiliar with how lambda works but am currently reading up on it. Any suggestion on how I would go about doing this?